# How to persist data in Kotlin Compose Multiplatform (pref. with spring data) alongside Jetpack Compose

Tags: gradle, spring-data-jpa, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

### Background

I currently experiment with [kotlin compose multiplatform](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/) where i can create a common codebase for different plattforms (e.g. desktop, ios, android, browser) with kotlin.
It seems that most of the code turns out to be based on Jetpack Compose (is still new for me).

### Current Issue

My issue started with the need to persist data from the application (e.g. into a db). I was not successfull at including spring boot data into my project (since thats something i already know how to handle).

But it seems like my configuration can't find `org.springframework.boot:*`, even though the libraries are getting resolved.

> Does someone know how to solve this general problem? Preferably some hints on why spring boot doesn't work?

#### What i tried

I tried injecting the [the relevant parts the spring initilizer](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project-kotlin&language=kotlin&platformVersion=3.0.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-jpa) gave me for including spring boot data.

Below, you see that the projects consists of two nested gradle projects where only the `common` subproject would contain the persistance logic.

[image: gradle structure]

Here are the changes i made to gradle:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")

    // ====== Change 1 ======
    // Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.7.22"
    //    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"    // this conflicts with kotlin("multiplatform")
    // ======================
}

// ====== Change 2 ======
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}
// ======================

kotlin {
    android()
    jvm("desktop")
    sourceSets {
        named("commonMain") {
            // ====== Change 4 ======
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }
            // ======================
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                implementation(compose.ui)

                // ====== Change 3 ======
                // Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA
                implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
                implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
                implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
                runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
                compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
                // ======================
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the outer build.gradle. It seems to be mainly managing the repositories

```kotlin
plugins {
    // this is necessary to avoid the plugins to be loaded multiple times
    // in each subproject's classloader
    kotlin("jvm") apply false
    kotlin("multiplatform") apply false
    id("com.android.application") apply false
    id("com.android.library") apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
        // ====== Change 5 ======
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And thats the error loading the gradle projects:

[image]

```
:desktop:jvmMain: Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:.
Required by:
    project :desktop > project :common
```

Even though i get this issue, the sources can import from spring library:

[image: import works]

Comment: I believe your question is just too broad to answer. First of all you shouldn't use Spring / Spring Boot in your KMM shared library, because Spring framework is mostly suitable for Backed applications. And there are a lot of approaches how to handle app data. You could store it in remote DB and access it through your Backend server or you could store data in local DB (e.g. SQLite).